# I am login facebook from Safari,but not from facebook app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am successfully login from my application with Safari when there is no facebook app install in my iPhone.But when facebook app exist in my phone,I am not able to login.

It shows,
"Invalid sso_key parameter.The key.com.Gl does not match any allowed allowed bundle IDs.Configure your iOS bundle ID at http://developers.facebook.com/apps/145000456..."

When I use developer bundle id,only I can login.Other people can not login with their facebook id because loginViewShowingLoggedInUser method is not call from facebook application..

I use Fasebook sdk earlier version.

```
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>

- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {
    NSLog(@"User logged in");
    self.checkInButton.hidden=NO;

}



- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {
    NSLog(@"User logged out");
    [self.checkInButton setHidden:YES];
}
```

Comment: did you configure your (IOS) app bundle identifier in Facebook app ?

Comment: Hmm..My bundle name and bundle identifier is same.

Comment: you can find your bundle identifier by clicking on your project in the project navigator  -> general , and under identity you will find the bundle identifier , then you have to configure an IOS app in Facebook apps with the bundle identifier we just found

Comment: I think you are missing something...Check you plist file again have you entered you fbid urlscheme as indicated by facebook... And in order to make other user login you have to make you app live...in dashboard go to settings fill you contact information and the put you app live

Comment: But I am successfully login with Safari from my app.